# Lightbox jQuery conflict with drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, lightbox, conflict

I'm a novice in jQuery and I need help.

I have incorporated lightbox and flexslider in the page and have resolved my initial problem of jQuery conflict between the two. Now, I am facing the dilemma of one of my scripts conflicting with my drop-down nav menu on my header. When I'm in a page with the lightbox scripts, the dropdown can't seem to be clicked anymore (just the topmost link option).

Here's the page I'm referring to: http://olivarezhomes.com/phase1.html

javascript files area:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script> $164 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>


<!-- jQuery Superfish -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hoverIntent.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersubs.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Flexslider -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Dropdown Mobile -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinynav.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>


<!-- jQuery PrettyPhoto -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "fade",  
      directionNav: true, 
      controlNav: true });});</script>

<!-- jQuery Lightbox -->
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I've got the same problem right now. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "fade",  
      directionNav: true, 
      controlNav: true });
});
```